# Is it possible to force a computer to join a domain when connected to the network?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to force computers, who are connected to the local network, to join the domain?

Comment: define force better, there is no way to force this unless you already have the local admins pw.  If you do then you can do the netdom trick (excluding fw issues).

Comment: Do you control these computers, or at least know a consistent administrator username/password on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "force" term is not enough precise to provide specific help.

You can use [netdom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788049%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from a central computer to join them to the domain remotely (providing both local admin account and a domain account with right to join computer).

Firewall on remote computer may block netdom from connecting and join it to the domain.

Comment: When a client is connected, it should automatically join the domain.

Comment: I see 2 ways: 1/Do a batch that scan computer on network and try to join them (assuming same local admin account all time). 2/Do your own master, so you can join domain during silent automated install of Windows. This is what companies does, for example using MDT from Microsoft which is free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Any computer for whom you have administrative privileges can be made part of the domain on command.

If you don't have local administrative privileges, you cannot make the machine become part of the domain.

Assumes you have certain administrative privileges within the domain.  You can be part of the admin group, or the right to do this can be assigned granularly.

Netdom.exe can be used for this purpose:

```
NETDOM [ ADD | COMPUTERNAME | HELP | JOIN | MOVE | QUERY | REMOVE |
         MOVENT4BDC | RENAMECOMPUTER | RESET | TRUST | VERIFY | RESETPWD ]
```

like:

```
netdom add /d:reskita mywksta /ud:mydomain\admin /pd:password
```